# Monotouch Dialog News style element with drill down capability

Tags: monotouch.dialog

In Montouch Dialog I want a News List style table of elements where I can have an image on the left, a main title, a value and be able to add a tapped event to then show the News Items Details.

I have played around with elements such as:

```
ImageStringElement, BadgeElement
```

... but none of these provide all the requirements that I want.

Any ideas or will I need to create a custom element. If so how would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own CustomCell with XCode and load the nib:

```
var cell =(CustomCell) tv.DequeueReusableCell("CellPlace");
if(cell==null)
cell = (CustomCell)Runtime.GetNSObject(NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("CustomCell",new CustomCell(),null).ValueAt(0));
```